# Need to optimize cell by cell comparison of excel files

Tags: excel, vbscript

Below is the code that i created as a POC towards an implementation for 2 excel file comparison (cell by cell)

This was just to test the logic, which works as expected, however i found out that for big data (hundreds of rows and columns) this approach using excel object is very time consuming. Approx time taken for comparing 130 rows and 248 columns was about 10 mins.

Is there any way that i can optimize this

Note: " the code is at basic level" kindly answer towards optimization only

```
 Dim a()
 Dim b()
 x = 0
 file1 = InputBox("Enter the first file")
 file2 = InputBox("enter the second file")

 'create FSO and check if the file exist
 Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    if (fso.fileExists(file1)) and (fso.fileExists(file2)) then
      MsgBox "The file exists"
    Else
      MsgBox "The file doesn't exists"
      ErrCount = 1
    End if

if Errcount <> 1 then 
'Create excel object for both the files and compare
    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
'Iterate from worksheets for both the file
    Set objFile1 = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(file1)
    objFile1Count = objFile1.Worksheets.count

    Set objFile2 = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(file2)
    objFile2Count = objFile2.Worksheets.count
    End if

  'sheet should be same
    if objFile1Count <> objFile2Count then
      ErrCount = 1
    End if

    ' Loop through the sheets
      if ErrCount <> 1 then
          For cnt = 1 to objFile1.Sheets.count
            Set file1Sheet = objFile1.Sheets(cnt)
            Set file2Sheet = objFile2.Sheets(cnt)
            'Check the sheet name
            if file1Sheet.Name <> file2Sheet.Name then
              ErrCount = 1
              Exit For
            Else
              'File 1
              file1RC = file1Sheet.usedrange.rows.count
              file1CC = file1Sheet.usedrange.columns.count
              'File 2
              file2RC = file2Sheet.usedrange.columns.count
              file2CC = file2Sheet.usedrange.columns.count

              'Iterate file
                For i = 2 to file1RC
                  For j = 1 to file1CC
                          ReDim Preserve a(x)
                          ReDim Preserve b(x)
                          a(x) = Trim(file1Sheet.Rows(i).columns(j).value)
                          b(x) = Trim(file2Sheet.Rows(i).columns(j).value)
                          file2getRC = i &"," &j 
                          file1getRC = i &"," &j

                          'Check compare and add color
                           File1Val = a(x)
                           File2Val = b(x)

                           if File1Val = File2Val then
                              'do nothing as the values matches
                           Else
                              RNC = split(file1getRC, ",")
                              Col = RNC(1)
                              Row = RNC(0)
                              Col = CInt(Col)

                              ty = file1Sheet.Rows(Row).Cells(1, Col).value
                              file1Sheet.Rows(Row).Cells(1, Col).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                              file2Sheet.Rows(Row).Cells(1, Col).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                              objFile1.Save
                              objFile2.Save
                           End if 
                          x=x+1
                  Next
                Next
               End if
            Next
    MsgBox "it works"
  Else
    MsgBox "No file added or cancelled" 
      End if
```

Comment: Requests for code optimization are better handled at [Code Review - Excel](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/excel).

Comment: When comparing data you definitly want to get your data into an `Array` and then sort through it in there. I agree with @Jeeped you will benefit nicely on Code Review with the instruction and information shared there.

Comment: If and when you do post on Code Review, make up your mind whether this is an [excel-vba] question or a [vbscript] question. While similar, they are **not** the same and combining both tags can only generate confusion unless you truly require working within both platforms (which at first glance you do not).

Comment: Thanks @jeeped

Yes, I will make the tag change - i just did so i could more people to help me out.

Comment: Thanks @Jean-PierreOosthuizen
Do you think if there is any other way apart from this that i could try it out ?